# Некорректная реакция на касание элемента GridView

Tags: android

У меня есть адаптер и в нем обработчик касания, который во-время касания выводит текст с того элемента, на котором было осуществлено действие.

Вот так выглядит мой адаптер:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TaskName>{
    private final String LOG = "ADAPTER_LOG";
    private AppCompatActivity context;
    private TextView nameView, countView;
    private TaskName taskName;


    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TaskName> taskNames){
        super(context, 0 , taskNames);
        this.context = (AppCompatActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, null);
        }

        taskName = getItem(position);
        nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
        nameView.setText(taskName.getTaskName());
        countView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_task);
        countView.setText(String.valueOf(taskName.getTaskNameId()));

        convertView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d(LOG, nameView.getText().toString());
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

      return convertView;
    }


}
```

Проблема в том, что выводит всегда первую запись. Почему так происходит и как мне это исправить ?

Comment: Т.е. текст в пунктах разный, а при клике одинаковый?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,  да именно так!(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реакция как раз таки правильная. 
Необходимо обращаться к данным по позиции.

```
Log.d(LOG, getItem(position).getTaskName());
```

Comment: Спасибо!  Не знал как нужно к позиции обращаться !